# Emptying ui-grid on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Is there any way to completely empty a ui-grid (filters,data, column and all)?

I'm trying to empty the grid on button-click so that a new http request can be made and the result displayed using the same grid without reloading the page.

I tried `$scope.gridOptions.length=0` but the data remains and on making an new request, the result gets appended to the previous result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To empty a ui-grid data you will need to reinitialize via any array syntax.

```
$scope.gridOptions.data= [];
```

To clear all filters ,columns, you will need to later reinitialize the gridOptions itself via object literal syntax.

```
$scope.gridOptions= {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the length of grid doesn't make any effect on data. Try this:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.gridOptions.data = [];` seems to work.. However it probably doesn't get rid of columns, which is what you wanted. In fact it clearly doesn't, this would be a normal thing to do if you wanted to clear the rows but keep the columns.

Comment: Provide more verbose answer to let other user understand what and why your solution is about.